# How to get TailwindCSS in HTML instead of Node.js

Tags: tailwind-css

My question is simple. How to get TailwindCSS in HTML and not via Npm/yarn etc?

Thanks

I tested from the documentation, but nothing seems to work. I've also tested Tailwind Material (HTML), but they still ask for NPM.

Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use tailwindcss without npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73855157/how-to-use-tailwindcss-without-npm)

Answer (score 0):

##### Solution

Use "**CDN**".

**Please note** that if you're not generating CSS using node.js, postcss, or the tailwind-cli, and **you're only applying a pre-built default Tailwind CSS file, you won't have the opportunity to take advantage of the benefits of Tailwind CSS** beyond the default available classes and define your own classes using Tailwind.

##### More information

[Get started with **TailwindCSS - Play CDN**](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn) - TailwindCSS Docs

[What's **CDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CDN) - MDN Docs

##### Example

```js
tailwind.config = {}
```

```html
<!-- need include <script> to <head> (read docs) -->
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com#.js"></script>

<!-- and can use default tailwindcss classes -->
<h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline text-clifford bg-red-500">
  Hello world!
</h1>
```

Comment: but in that case, what if I need to use their CLI or something else that comes from node, knowing that I have my PHP8 website?

Comment: **If you generate CSS using the CLI, it won't generate it live.** You need to install Node.js on your development machine and use a framework like Vite. After that, you set up the configuration according to the documentation. You create the code, and from this development code, you **need to generate a so-called "production" code** using the command "npm run build". **PHP has no connection to CLI**.

Comment: If you don't have the opportunity or don't want to use such advanced tools, **you can to loading the pre-built Tailwind CSS file**. In this case, you **don't need PHP either**. You just need to insert the script I suggested into the head section of your HTML code, and you can use the default classes in your code.