# Tailwind Using bigger percentage of width on smaller screen doesn't work

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make `w-1/2` on large screens and `w-full` on smaller screens but it doesn't work with that way.

###### Doesn't work `w-full lg:w-1/2` (Why?)

```html
<div class="inline-flex flex-wrap w-full lg:w-1/2 mx-auto justify-center">
```

However if I tried it in vice versa it works.

###### Works `w-1/2 lg:w-full`

```html
<div class="inline-flex flex-wrap w-1/2 lg:w-full mx-auto justify-center">
```

What should I do?
I tried adding another widths and asking GPT but I couldn't manage it to work.

Comment: try adding `<div class="inline-flex flex-wrap lg:w-full w-1/2 mx-auto justify-center">`

Comment: Since Tailwind works in both cases, it can be inferred that it doesn't run the Tailwind compiler server during development - usually via the `npm run dev` command. When referring to the production version, either the browser cache is tricking it, or the `npm run build` command hasn't been executed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The provided codes in the question work visibly during testing. This was the expected outcome, as we are discussing default Tailwind CSS classes.

By default, you can see the `sm`/`md` view. After running, in the top right corner, you will find a "Full page" link. Clicking on it allows you to see how the `lg:` code works.

```js
tailwind.config = {}
```

```html
<!-- need include <script> to <head> (read docs) -->
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com#.js"></script>

<!-- and can use default tailwindcss classes -->
<!-- Your First Code -->
<div class="inline-flex flex-wrap w-full lg:w-1/2 mx-auto justify-center bg-red-500">
  Test
</div>

<!-- Your Second Code -->
<div class="inline-flex flex-wrap w-1/2 lg:w-full mx-auto justify-center bg-orange-500">
  Test
</div>
```

If you're developing using tailwindcss, never forget to execute the `npm run dev` command when using Vite.

If you're specifically working with the tailwind CLI, then following the documentation, you can achieve automatic native code generation during development using the command `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch`.

##### More information

- [TailwindCSS with TailwindCLI](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) - TailwindCSS Docs
- [TailwindCSS with Vite](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite) - TailwindCSS Docs
- [TailwindCSS with CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76516921/how-to-get-tailwindcss-in-html-instead-of-node-js) - StackOverflow answer